# Inner product on a complex field defined by norms

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, normed-spaces, inner-products

I see that if $F=\mathbb{R}$, we can define $\langle u,v\rangle = ||u+v||^2 - ||u-v||^2$ using basic arithmetics. However, if $F = \mathbb{C}$, we have $||u+v||^2 - ||u-v||^2 = 2u^*v + 2v^*u$. So we need to define some other norms to establish an explicit rule.

I was given the hint to use $||u+iv||^2$ and $||u-iv||^2$, but my arithmetics with complex numbers are bad and I'm not sure how to come to an explicit conclusion. That is, how to write $\langle u,v\rangle$ using $||u+iv||^2$, $||u-iv||^2$, $||u+v||^2$, and $||u-v||^2$.

This is very basic question, there's probably some cancelling rule of complex numbers I don't know. I'd appreciated if someone can walk me through it. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: You mean $|u+v|^2$ etc. Note that $|u+v|^2=(u+v)(\overline u+\overline v)=|u|^2+|v|^2+u\overline v+\overline uv$. Now what about $|u+iv|^2$ etc.

Comment: what do you mean $|u+v|^2$? What I mean by $||u+v||^2$ is the 2-norm squared, which seems to be the same thing you're describing. Is this an notation issue?

Comment: Then what do **you** mean by $u^*v$?

Comment: conjugate/hermitian transpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polarisation identity for real vector spaces is 
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \dfrac14 \sum_{k = \pm1} k||u + kv||^2$$
and for complex vector spaces it is 
$$\langle u,v\rangle = \dfrac14 \sum_{k = \pm1,\pm i} k||u + kv||^2$$.